# How do you document multiple functions in a single man (.Rd) file, in package source?

Tags: r, function, package, manual

For example, I have a file foo.R with the contents:

```
#FILE: foo.R
foo <- function() "foo"
bar <- function() "bar"
```

This forms the R code for my package. I want to document both `foo` and `bar` in a single .Rd file: when the user enters `help(foo)` or `help(bar)`, the result should be the same (to bring up the help page that documents both `foo` and `bar`). (Similarly, `help(cos)` and `help(sin)` result in identical behavior.)

Executing `package.skeleton(name="pkg1", path="OUTDIR/", code_files="INDIR/foo.R")` creates separate .Rd files for `foo` and `bar` in the "man" subdirectory.

How do I create a single .Rd file that documents both `foo` and `bar`, and that that `help` can find?

I am following [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.pdf), trying to create a *very simple* package *without* using any tools other than those that ship with a basic R installation (no Roxygen, for example), plus the system shell (e.g., bash or, in the present case, Windows command line, for executing e.g., `R CMD build`.)

Comment: an example [here](https://github.com/stla/OwenQ/blob/master/R/pOwen.R).

Comment: Ah you don't want to use Roxygen ? Then see the compiled [Rd file](https://github.com/stla/OwenQ/blob/master/man/powen.Rd).

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent What part of your [Rd file](https://github.com/stla/OwenQ/blob/master/man/powen.Rd) allows `help` to behave in the intended manner?

Comment: I don't master Rd files, I'm using Roxygen. But to reply to your question this is probably `\name` and `\alias`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent +1. `\alias` is the key.